# Will disabling directx rendering help to low the cpu and memory usage?

Tags: delphi, optimization, directx

Sorry for the question asked before and it was not clear. Now I am trying to be more specific:

I am injecting a dll into an old simple 2d game and trying to low its cpu and memory usage when it's inactive(it's window mode). For now what I can think up is to hook directx functions and disable rendering when it's inactive. But:

1.Is that possible? I mean if this game can run properly if doing so.

2.If yes, is this helpful to low cpu and memory usage?

Comment: Well, let's see. Based on the info you've provided (none), how can we suggest you do this.... Same answer: No info, no ideas. Seriously, how do you expect an answer to "I have an app. How to optimize it for something with no more info than that?"

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given much information, so the best I can give you is..

- Keep track of entities that need to always be updated [timers,etc], and *update only them* when the window is inactive.
- Don't draw anything while the window is inactive.

It's not a simple task to reduce memory usage based on whether a window is active or inactive.